# Creating a loop in R to avoid repetitive code

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get my head around using loops in R so that I can avoid the repetitive code I used to format a table.

I'm just starting the process of learning loops to automate tasks, so there's been mostly blank stares up to this point. The long version of the code I used does the job, but wouldn't be practical on a larger scale.

```
library(DT)

##  Create data frame containing test results for Students A - H.   
A <- c(69, 64, 70, 57, 80, 34, 45, 56, 96)
B <- c(70, 74, 68, 76, 71, 56, 56, 45, 30)
C <- c(84, 58, 87, 78, 67, 67, 43, 34, 56)
D <- c(78, 83, 68, 72, 90, 48, 23, 23, 46)    
E <- c(79, 55, 91, 71, 34, 26, 76, 67, 75)    
F <- c(80, 72, 64, 45, 66, 76, 45, 56, 54)    
G <- c(90, 67, 76, 51, 45, 59, 33, 64, 34)    
H <- c(60, 59, 88, 90, 76, 34, 43, 72, 45)    
student_results <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H)   

##  Create table of data frame, highlighting marks >= 85 in 'aquamarine'
##  Marks < 50 highlighted in 'coral'
datatable(student_results) %>%      
  formatStyle('A',
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine"))) %>%      
  formatStyle('B',
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine"))) %>%      
  formatStyle('C',
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine"))) %>%      
  formatStyle('D',
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine"))) %>%      
  formatStyle('E',
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine"))) %>%      
  formatStyle('F',
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine"))) %>%      
  formatStyle('G',
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine"))) %>%      
  formatStyle('H',
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine"))
```

The code I came up with does the job but is very repetitive. I've been trying to figure out how to either get a loop to run the formatStyle() function over every column in the table, or find some other function that performs the same task, but haven't had any success.

Comment: What package does `datatable` and `formatStyle` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piping `a %>% b() %>% b() %>% b()` is the same as repeatedly evaluating `b(b(b(a)))`, so your `for` loop version would look like repeated applications of your function:

```
> sr = datatable(student_results)
> for(L in LETTERS[1:8]){
     sr = formatStyle(sr, L, 
          backgroundColor = styleInterval(
              c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine")))}
> sr
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(DT)
#colnames(student_results)[2:ncol(student_results)] #if you need selected columns
datatable(student_results) %>% 
          formatStyle(colnames(student_results),backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(50,85), c("coral", "white", "aquamarine")))
```

Comment: And this is even simpler than what I was looking for, thanks again!